# CodeDeploy Script does not exist at specified location - appspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy my app on AWS with CodeDeploy.

Here is my appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0

os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/todos // <== this dir already exists in my instance

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    ...

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/prerequisites
      timeout: 1200
      runas: root

  AfterInstall:
    ...
  ApplicationStart:
    ...
  ValidateService:
    ...
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error Code: ScriptMissing
>
> Script Name: scripts/prerequisites
>
> Message: Script does not exist at specified location:
>   /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/2e557520-7ffe-4881-8c7c-991952c56e05/d-UWR3Z01FE/deployment-archive/scripts/prerequisites
>
> Log Tail: LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall

My scripts are stored in a file called 'scripts' that is found at the root of my app.

What am I missing? or doing wrong? If anyone could help me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so it seems that the problem was simply a typo. I forgot to write the file extension to my scripts (.sh)

Like so:

```
BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/prerequisites.sh // <--- this fixed it
      timeout: 1200
      runas: root
```

Hope it helps anyone.